# Don't send data if form invalid

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-analytics

I'm wondering if anyone has done this before? Basically, you have a form and and say a user inputs invalid data. The form will still send tracking to GA upon submit.

How do you prevent this from happening? Currently my analytics code is inline on the submit button but wondering if this should be moved into my javascript and create an if statement?

```
if ($(this.form).valid()) {
    // Trigger GA Submit
    _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Friday Deals', 'Music and Sports', '[48r6KevWQkGNIgjRc95owg or xwPuPgV9D0ifMwjRc95swg]']);
} else {
    // Form not valid
    alert("Form is not valid");
}
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Yea of course you can. On submit you check if the form is valid (you define what valid means) and if it is valid then track and submit form

Comment: Do you use AJAX to submit form ??

Comment: @Filth What is the question, "has someone done this before?"? It looks  like it should work, have you tried it?